# Is append and appendChild getting overwritten?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jspm

I am using `jspmBundleSFX`.

In one of my `index.html` in one of my directories, when I type, `$("#sfsdfasfsdaf").append` in console.

I get `function(){return x(this,arguments,function(a){if(1===this.nodeType||11===this.nodeType||9===this.nodeType){var b=s(this,a);b.appendChild(a)}})}` Chrome says it belongs to `main.js` which is the bundled and uglified js.

`$("#sfsdfasfsdaf")` Does not even exist, what is hapenning?

This also happens with ids that exist `$("#canvas").append` I get the same result.
`appendChild` however returns `undefined`

In another `index.html` in another directory everything works absolutely fine. I have no idea how to fix this problem. Both `index.html` include the `main.js` uglified file.

**EDIT:** I replaced `$("#canvas");` with `document.getElementById('canvas');` It works fine now. However I still have no idea why this problem was happening. Did some script overwrite or have conflicts with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a jQuery object. It may be an empty jQuery object (if the element doesn't exist or, more accurately, if no elements match the selector) but it is still a jQuery object.

As such, it still has all the jQuery methods, such as `.append`. It just won't do anything if you call it.

Vanilla JavaScript, however, gives `null` if the element doesn't exist (eg. `document.getElementById('herpaderp')` will be `null`), and `null` doesn't have the methods that an element would have such as `appendChild`.

Personally I consider this a good thing in general - if I say I want an element and it doesn't exist, chances are there are bigger problems and an error should be thrown, but jQuery will continue happily along.

Answer (score 3):

> $("#sfsdfasfsdaf") Does not even exist, what is hapenning

The reason is `$(selector)` will always return a `jQuery` object regardless whether there are matching elements existing or not. That object will always include a property `append` which is a function. There is no jQuery method `appendChild` which is why you see undefined.

Beyond that it is not clear at all what you aare trying to do or what higher level problem you have

Comment: When I repeated for a id of a div that exists, I get the same result. Was jQuery unable to find that object?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do in the first place. The console logs you are using don't have any practical application